# Для чего может понадобиться extern class

Tags: c++

Что дает такая конструкция?

```
 extern class Class obj {};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что не правильно в коде на картинках.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где Вы встретили такую запись?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это ошибочная запись, о чём Вас должен был предупредить компилятор. `extern` (в таком ключе) применяется только к переменным и функциям, а у Вас нет ни того, ни другого. Если же немного модифицировать пример:

```
extern class Class 
{
} instance;
```

, то получится, что мы объявили переменную `instance` типа `Class`.

---

Код выше это просто сокращенная форма такой записи:

```
class Class 
{
};

extern Class instance;
```

Т.е. мы определили новый класс `Class` и объявили объект типа `Class` с именем `instance`. Где-то мы должны определить этот объект, иначе при его использовании получим ошибку на этапе компоновки.

Comment: почему не написать просто extern Class instance;

Comment: @StanislavPetrov, потому что синтаксис языка такого не позволяет. Что есть `Class` в этой записи?

Comment: ваш код говорит о том что где то есть объявление типа Class и объявляет объект этого класса. С таким объявлением объекта не обязательно подключать хедер с настоящим объявлением класса Class?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

К вопросу зачем слово `extern` вообще нужно:

Допустим у нас есть некоторая глобальная переменная `int var`, эта переменная одна на всю программу (оставим вопрос о нежелательности глобальных переменных за кадром, пример синтетический). Проект состоит из нескольких файлов `.cpp`, в каждом нужен доступ к этой переменной. Как реализовать?

Вариант 1

```
// header.h 
void foo();

int var;
```

```
// foo.cpp
#include "header.h"

int var = 42;

void foo() { 
    var = 42;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    foo();
    std::cout << var;
}
```

Но нет, при компиляции получаем вот это:

```
foo.cpp:4:5: error: redefinition of 'int var'
 int var;
     ^~~
In file included from foo.cpp:2:0:
header.h:5:5: note: 'int var' previously declared here
 int var;
     ^~~
```

Это все потому что нам нужно *объявить* (declare) переменную в заголовочном файле, а мы ее *определяем* (define).

В `header.h` рядом с переменной мы объявили функцию foo:

```
void foo();
```

По сути мы сказали компилятору - "Вот так выглядит функция `foo`, но ее определение будет потом (возможно в другом файле)". Как сказать тоже самое о переменных?

Нам нужен инструмент для объявления переменных.

Вот это и есть `extern`. Меняем одну строчку в `header.h`:

```
// header.h 
void foo();

extern int var;
```

И все работает:

```
$ g++ main.cpp foo.cpp
$ a.exe
42
```

`extern` работает и с функциями, по сути эти два объявления эквивалентны:

```
extern void foo(); // так обычно не пишут, но это верно 
void foo();
```

Начиная с С++11 появился еще один [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c11) использования.

`extern` работает только с функциями и переменными, но не с классами/структурами, ваша конструкция не имеет смысла (и не скомпилируется). Если надо объявить класс то надо писать так

```
class Foo;
struct Bar;
```

P.S Еще extern используется для [связки](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) C++ с С (и другими языками), но это уже другая история...